# Replacement specific identifer with regex

Tags: java, regex, identifier

I have a java regex for replacing all instances of a specific identifier in a script.

This is the search regex that searchers for the "foo" identifier:

```
([^\w_]|^)foo([^\w\d_]|$)
```

And this is the replacement:

```
$1bar$2
```

Doing a replaceAll in something like

```
for foo: [1,2,3];foo&&foo;
```

works well, it outputs

```
for bar: [1,2,3];bar&&bar;
```

However, when we apply this to a string with two instances of the identifier separated by a single character, it only replaces the first:

```
foo&foo
```

outputs

```
bar&foo
```

This happens, I think, because the first match is "bar&" and so when analyzing the rest of the string no other match is found.

Is there a way to fix this by changing the regex only?

Comment: If all you need is replace `foo` with `bar` why can't you use : `input.replaceAll( "foo", "bar")`; Here `foo` is the regex. Is the question missing something?

Comment: i want to replace entire identifiers only. Lets say I have `refoo > foo`. If i were to do `input.replaceAll( "foo", "bar")` i would get `rebar > bar`. I want, instead `refoo > bar`.

Comment: the question is what is the difference between refoo and bar&foo (in a programmatic way I mean)

Comment: `refoo` is an identifier, and its not the same as `foo`. `bar&foo` are two identifiers separated by the `&` operator. In this case `bar&foo` should be replaced by `bar&bar`. By identifier I mean identifier in a Python script, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost looking for `\bfoo\b` as your regex otherwise use lookarounds `(?<=\W|^)foo(?=\W|$)`. In both ways replacement string is `bar`.

*Note: `\d` and `_` are subsets of `\w` and `[^\w]` is equal to `\W`*

Comment: `(?<=\W|^)foo(?=\W|$)` is semantically same as `\bfoo\b` but is suitable for customizing character classes if needed.